# format output data in pandas to_html

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas' to_html to generate output file, when data are written to the file they have many digits after the decimal point. The pandas' to_html float_format method can limit the digits, but when I used 'float_format' as below:

```
DataFormat.to_html(header=True,index=False,na_rep='NaN',float_format='%10.2f')
```

it raise a exception:

```
typeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the `to_html` docs:

```
float_format : one-parameter function, optional
    formatter function to apply to columns' elements if they are floats
    default None
```

You need to pass a function.  For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1.0/3]})
>>> df
          A
0  0.333333

>>> print df.to_html()
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td> 0.333333</td>
    </tr>
[...]
```

but

```
>>> print df.to_html(float_format=lambda x: '%10.2f' % x)
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
[...]
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>      0.33</td>
    </tr>
[...]
```

Answer (score 9):

Without a `lambda`, you can pass a `str.format` function directly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df.to_html(float_format='{:10.2f}'.format)
```